# Как быть, если ответ дан в комментарии?

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии, ответы

Я бываю тут не часто, и смотрю в первую очередь вопросы без ответов или без принятых ответов. Там, где ответ есть и принят, делать уже нечего.

Но часто попадаю на вопросы, где ответ дан в комментарии, как тут: [Ввести число, вывести его реверс (не каждого цифру отдельно, а как значение одной переменной)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/934223/%d0%92%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be)

Давать свой ответ уже некрасиво, это как плагиат получается. Но и вопрос висит как неотвеченный.

"Кто виноват" понятно, а "Что делать"?